# Convert pdf file received in string variable to byte array in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to develop an application in C# which takes data from Service1(3rd party), processes it and then sends data to Service2(again 3rd party).

The data I am trying to receive, process and send is a **pdf** file

From Service1, I am receiving pdf file in a ***string*** variable.

e.g.

```
response.Content = "%PDF-1.4 \n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Pages 2 0 R\n/Type /Catalog\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Pages\n/Kids [ 3 0 R 17 0 R ]\n/Count 2\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Page\n/Parent 2 0 R\n/Resources <<\n/XObject << /Im0 8 0 R >>\n/ProcSet 6 0 R
>>\n/MediaBox [0 0 ..."
```

Now, Service2 requires PDF data to be in ***byte[]*** form

How do I convert *response.Content* i.e. *string* to *byte[]?*

FYI -

I have tried below method, but it didn't work. I am able to open file but it shows all junk values.

```
byte[] bitmapData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.Content);
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: Well, I've already looked into that post and tried different ways too, but still I'm not getting data in proper format.

Comment: what do you mean with 'I am able to open file'?

Comment: I mean earlier I was using byte[] bitmapData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Content); .. after which I tried to open pdf file, but pdf reader said 'file is corrupted' or something like that

Comment: The `\n`that are on the PDF string are literally like that? If that is the case, then the string contains scaped (modified) characters. You will have to replace \n with newlines.

Comment: _From Service1, I am receiving pdf file in a string variable._ - This is a problem. In c# a string contain unicode characters. A pdf file contains bytes.

Comment: Yes. That's how it exactly is as I seen in debug mode. And how do I replace \n with newlines? I didn't get that..  isn't both same?

Comment: Yes Wimmel.. That's where I thought problem is.. But since Service1 being from 3rd party reputed developer, I scrapped that thought.

Comment: If you open the file with a text editor, what do you see?

Comment: Something like this - 

%PDF-1.4 
1 0 obj
<<
/Pages 2 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [ 3 0 R 17 0 R ]
/Count 2
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources <<
/XObject << /Im0 8 0 R >>
/ProcSet 6 0 R >>
/MediaBox [0 0

Comment: That looks ok (assuming you have multiple lines, not just one). Hard to tell what is going on. If you could get the original PDF file and test for differences, it would probably be clear. Sorry.

Comment: I actually don't have Source/Original file.. Just know that Service1 sends pdf data in that  format. Nvm, thanks.

Comment: I agree with @Wimmel: as soon as you have a Pdf as a string, you quite likely have damaged it. Can you not access the web service 1 response as raw bytes?

Comment: Yes mkl.. was just looking into it again and saw that.. Actually I was using _RestSharp_ for my call to service and I was referring to string _Content_ variable from response. Just saw that there is another variable _RawBytes_ which is byte[].. Anyways thanks again all of you. I'll update my post.

Comment: As that resolves the issue, you should make that an actual answer, not an appendix of your question, and accept that answer as soon as you are allowed to (As fast As I know you have to wait some hours before you can accept an own answer).

Comment: Thanks, IRestResponse.RawBytes works fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found that it was not *Service1* which was sending data in string format, it's just I was using `IRestResponse.Content`, a string variable from *RestSharp* instead of using `IRestResponse.RawBytes`, a byte[] variable.

Comment: Short but could be more clearly expressed ;)

Comment: Using `IRestResponse.RawBytes` is really helped.