# Convert String to Bytes Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I used the following code to convert a bytes array to a string:

```
byte[] saltBytes;

// ... filling the array with some values

for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(saltBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
}

string salt = builder.ToString();
```

Now,  I would like to revert this process and convert my string to a bytes array. I was reading this question: [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp).

The answer mentions:

> If you already have a byte array then you will need to know what type
>   of encoding was used to make it into that byte array.

I'm not sure about the encoding used in the snippet I posted. Does this have to do with the `ToString("x2")` part?

Comment: You don't have to worry about encoding as you converting yourself: single byte to two characters (padded with `0` if less than `0xF`).

Comment: By "encoding" they are referring to UTF8, UTF16, etc. But as @Sinatr said, you don't need that. You just need to go from a hex string back to byte.