# how can i compare two string with same presentaion but different byte[]? c#

Tags: c#

How can i compare this two value? is there any idea?

Please look at this image and tell me what can i do?

[image]

1- The code

2- variable values and it seams the same!

3- The output that shows it is not OK! and these values are not the same!

4- I understand that the only different between these two values are in 2 bytes of them. (I use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp) for getting byte[] of string with UTF8 property)

**Solution:**

I wrote this extension method to solve the problem:

```
public static class FarsiExtension
{
    public static string FixYEH(this String instance)
    {
        return instance.Replace('ي', 'ی');
    }
}
```

and you can use it this way:

```
string fixedValue = stateKhedmat.ToString().FixYEH();
```

Comment: post full code here please not only screenshot

Comment: How do we type this arabic? text? Please add it into the question?

Comment: Post the text of the two values

Comment: i try this too and get me false again!

Comment: you can try some of the different cultures https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488

Comment: پایان خدمت and پايان خدمت . it is persian/Farsi not arabic ;)

Comment: You could try to normalize the strings first using `String.Normalize`. If the glyphs are identical, and just use different codepoints, then normalizing should return a canonical form that you can compare.

Comment: @Dirk I've tested normalize and it sadly does not work, i've tried all 4 options.

Comment: One of the strings contains an [ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06cc/index.htm), the other contains an [ARABIC LETTER YEH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/064a/index.htm). I'm not familiar with Farsi or Arabic so I don't know if they should look the same when part of a word, but on their own they look slightly different.

Comment: Thanks Pieter Witvoet. I get char[] of string and replace it with the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

That they look like the same character doesn't mean it is the same character, as you see in the byte code.

I figure the only way to make these strings match is to always normalize the strings that you get by replacing 1 with the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're have padding issues, convert both string to bytes and remove padding and convert back to string. this should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with [`CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.compareoptions), but I am not sure how to test for false positives:

```
string s1 = "پایان خدمت", s2 = "پايان خدمت"; char c1 = 'ی', c2 = 'ي';
var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;

Debug.Print(ci.Compare(s1, s2, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) + ""); // 0
Debug.Print(ci.Compare(s1, s2                               ) + ""); // 1

Debug.Print(ci.IndexOf(s1, c1, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) + ""); // 2
Debug.Print(ci.IndexOf(s1, c1                               ) + ""); // 2

Debug.Print(ci.IndexOf(s1, c2, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) + ""); // 2
Debug.Print(ci.IndexOf(s1, c2                               ) + ""); // -1
```