# How do I wrap this code as a method?

Tags: c#

```
public class CustomFont
{
    public string ChangeFont(string font, string target)
    {
        PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
        int fontLength = Properties.Resources.font.Length;
        byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.font;
        System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);
        pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
        target.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], target.Font.Size);
    }
}

I tried this but errors were shown that 'App.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'font'.
```

Okay so I edited the code following everybody's answers and it is almost working now. The problem is, what method should I use for `byte[]`?

```
public void ChangeFont(string font, TextBox target)
        {
            PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
            int fontLength = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(font).Length;
            byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.font;
            System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);
            pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
            target.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], target.Font.Size);
        }
```

Comment: If the error says so then I think there's no entry for font in resources. Can you show your resources file ?

Comment: View the properties window of your project and select the "Resources" section. If it says you have no resources then you need to add one and add the required settings.

Comment: There are much more issues with this code. target is of type string and the string type I know has no Font property. You did not return a result although the method signature say you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a string from your resources by name.

You can't write it like

```
Properties.Resources.font;
```

You have to use the `ResourceManager`

```
string myString = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(font);
```

And then you can do whatever you want with that string.

But your method has a lot of other things why you will get following problems; for example no return value.

Comment: And what method should I use for `byte[]`?

Comment: Have a look at [converting string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)