# Convert a string into a byte array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have a string,

```
string Var="11001100"
```

I want to convert it into a byte array.

```
bArray[0]=0x00;
bArray[1]=0x00;
bArray[2]=0x01;
bArray[3]=0x01;
bArray[4]=0x00;
bArray[5]=0x00;
bArray[6]=0x01;
bArray[7]=0x01;
```

Can anybody guide me in this? I tried the following code, but I get the data in ASCII. I do not want that.

```
bArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(var);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Do you mean *bit* array instead?

Comment: I want byte array only.I tried that Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(var); I do not want the data in acii i.e 48 for 0 and so on. I want to retain the binary string.

Comment: or you could do ascii arithmetics and subtract the ascii value of '0', which is 48

Comment: @FakeCaleb it's not a duplicate I think actually. Try to see Dmitry's answer.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Now I've seen OPs comment you maybe right, but it wasn't clear (even now) what he actually meant

Comment: that duplicate has an *answer* that answers *this*, but not the duplicate question itself...
the desired output is the OP second code section

Comment: does `bArray[0]=0x00;` represent the last digit in `Var` ?

Comment: what would be the outcome for this input: `string Var="10101100";` ?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string Var = "11001100";

byte[] bArray = Var
  .Select(item => (byte) (item == '0' ? 1 : 0))
  .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, bArray
  .Select((value, index) => $"bArray[{index}]=0x{value:X2};")));
```

Outcome:

```
bArray[0]=0x00;
bArray[1]=0x00;
bArray[2]=0x01;
bArray[3]=0x01;
bArray[4]=0x00;
bArray[5]=0x00;
bArray[6]=0x01;
bArray[7]=0x01;
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I get the data in ASCII. I do not want that.

Then you need the string representation of the chars. You get it using the `ToString` method. This would be the old scool way simply using a reversed for-loop:

```
string Var="11001100";

byte [] bArray = new byte[Var.Length];

int countForward = 0;
for (int i = Var.Length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    bArray[countForward] = Convert.ToByte(Var[i].ToString());
    countForward++;
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that `bArray` should contain *inversed* values: `'1' -> 0` and `'0' -> 1`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have the feeling that OP is reading the input from right to left (little endian fashion). Therefore I chose the reversed for loop

Comment: I see; we need a better test example to distinguish between these two possibilities...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko lets see whether he answers my question from the comment

Comment: well, in case of, say, `"11010101"` the outcomes are *different*: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` (my understanding - bytes reversing) and `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` (your reading - little/big endian). The test case provided `"11001100"` can't help to chose the right one (alas!)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I agree, same holds for the test case from my comment. Lets wait and see what and if OP responds to my comment

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for your question:

```
string value = "11001100";
int numberOfBits = value.Length;
var valueAsByteArray = new byte[numberOfBits];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBits; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = ((byte)(value[i] - 0x30)) == 0 ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
}
```

Edit: Forgot the inversion.