# MySQL BINARY type representation

Tags: c#, mysql, connector

There is a MySQL query parameter of type `BINARY`. Binary values in MySQL can be represented like `x'1f7a8e'`. However, when adding a parameter of type `MySqlDbType.Binary` to a `MySqlCommand` the query is formed with the value represented as `_binary '1f7a8e'` which causes the query to not find the row. Below you can see a code example of how the MySQL API is being used.

```
var baz = "1f7a8e";
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz=@baz");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@baz", MySqlDbType.Binary).Value = baz;

// Execute query and read result
```

What would be the correct way of using a binary value as a parameter?

Comment: did you try `Stream` or `byte[]`?

Comment: This seems like a strange design and/or scenario.  Does it not work if you simply convert the string to bytes as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to store a `Guid` as a `BINARY(16)`.

First I tried `guid.ToByteArray()` which did not work. Then I tried `guid.ToString().Replace("-", "")` which also failed.

Thanks to @daniel-a-white I then tried `guid.ToString().Replace("-", "")` and then converted the resulting hexadecimal number into a byte array (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/3742598)) and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `GUID` as `Binary (16)`

```
UNHEX(REPLACE(@baz, "-",""))
```

This will return binary(16).

And to SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE HEX(baz) = @baz
```