# Xamarin Forms: convert Object to Byte Array and vice versa

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to convert object like instance of my class Message (string id, string message, string datetime) in Byte Array. Send it to server, and server send the same message to other client. At least I need to convert this Byte Array into Message

I try BinaryFormatter with MemoryStream but doesn't work with UWP

Comment: if all your properties are string, just serialize it to json.  This is much easier to deal with than binary serialization.

Comment: Of according to said Jason, i would use **json**. In my app i obtain a serialize object from a rest and desserialize and i serialize and send to rest again. There is a response in this link, i wish that help you: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp`