# How to convert string array to byte array in c#

Tags: c#

So i have a string

```
string enc = ""hx0.+dhx0-pdhx0pzdhx0xx";
```

This is encrypted and when decrypted has the hexadecimal values, the starting values are 
"0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00"

Then this

```
string decrypted = encryptDecrypt(enc);
```

then this
    then i divided it after every comma to with the split command
    string[] hi = decrypted.Split(',');

When i check using this code

```
foreach (var item in hi )
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

it shows all the hexadecimal in side it
i want to turn string array values which are 
0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00 and more into byte array values which are 
0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00 too not some other values

Comment: The `Convert.ToByte` method will convert a `string` to a `byte`, e.g. `var b = Convert.ToByte(hexString, 16);`.  You just have to do that for each element in whatever way you deem appropriate, e.g. using `Array.ConvertAll`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but check out Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item);

Answer (score 1):

Is that the only string, or does that value change? Does your array need to be dynamic?

```
     string [] arrayString = new string []; //Your Array.

     byte [] arrayByte = new byte[arrayString.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.Length; i++)
     {
          arrayByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(arrayString[i], 16);
     }
```

Comment: This code will take in any string type array of any size and convert it to a byte array of any size. Keep in mind it doesn't overwrite your string array but if you wanted to add a line of code w/in the for loop to do that you can.

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Could not find any recognizable digits.'
i gete this error while trying to run    Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, h => Convert.ToByte(h, 16));

Comment: Remember that arrays start with 0. Take out the “=“ and it shouldn’t crash.

Answer (score 1):

Sample input:

```
String[] hi = "00,01,fe,ff".Split(',');
```

Conversion using a lambda function to convert each hexadecimal string to a byte:

```
Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, h => Convert.ToByte(h, 16));
```

If you want a different kind of delegate:

```
Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, HexToByte);

private Byte HexToByte(String h) 
{
    return Convert.ToByte(h, 16);
}
```

Same, with an expression-bodied function:

```
Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, HexToByte);

private Byte HexToByte(String h) => Convert.ToByte(h, 16);
```

Or yet a different kind of delegate:

```
Converter<String, Byte> hexToByte = h => Convert.ToByte(h, 16);
Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, hexToByte);
```

`Array.ConvertAll` is doing the real work. Conversion from hex is either a trivial idea that can be done inline or an important idea that can be given a name and/or a full implementation block.

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Could not find any recognizable digits.'
i gete this error while trying to run    Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, h => Convert.ToByte(h, 16));

Comment: It works for "0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00". You must have some other characters in the string that aren't hex digits or the 0x prefix, or separating commas. Or perhaps you just have a 0x without following hex digits.

Comment: FormatException is as informative as it could be so: `Byte[] b = Array.ConvertAll(hi, h => { try { return Convert.ToByte(h, 16); } catch (FormatException ex) { throw new FormatException($@"Can't parse ""{h}""", ex);} });`

Answer (score 0):

Convert each of the strings into byte and then store it to `str` variable.

```
byte[,] str = new byte[50,50];
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in hi)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.ToString());
    str[i] = arr;
    i++;
}
```

For more information, see this [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

For some text is not Ascii that you can use Utf-8 to convert string to byte.

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item);
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert from a string to a byte array, you can use the GetBytes method:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item);
```

Comment: GetBytes takes as argument a char[] or string not string[]