# Sending PDF base64 using POST web request

Tags: api, xamarin, post, http-post, webrequest

I have a task which I need to upload a pdf converted to base64 string to Http post. I tried it using refit before but I failed to upload it. Now, I am trying a difference approach.

I used the web request POST method, First I converted the PDF to base64 but on the part that I call the stream.write method, I'm having an error since the file is already converted to base64 string and the stream.write paramater is byte array.

Also, how can I add these to the body using web request?

"mime": "application/pdf",

"data": "base64-data="

```
 string pdfBase64;

 const string pdfFileName = "file.pdf";
    
                    using (var pdfStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(pdfFileName))
                    {
                        using (var pdfReader = new StreamReader(pdfStream))
                        {
                            var fileContents = await pdfReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                            pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents));
                        }
                    }
    
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://goodmorning-axa-dev.azure-api.net/upload");
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentLength = pdfBase64.Length;
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";             
                    request.Headers.Add("x-axa-api-key", apiKey);
    
                    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    stream.Write(pdfBase64, 0, pdfBase64.Length);
                    stream.Close();
    
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, sr.ReadToEnd(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    
                    sr.Close();
                    stream.Close();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Jason the problem is that, the requirement wants a pdf converted to base64 string. I already did the conversion but the stream.write method needs a byte array parameter. do I have to convert it again to byte array after converting to base64 string?

Comment: A glance at your "requirements" image shows that is expecting a JSON object, so I'm really not sure what you're doing with the stream.  There are many, many questions already answered about posting JSON

Comment: @Jason because I also need to send a pdf file that is converted to base64

Comment: @Jason I’m still new to this so I’m kinda lost. still doing some research

Comment: 1) create an class to model the data required by the API, 2) serialize it to json, 3) POST using one of the many, many, many existing tutorials on posting json

Comment: @error404  From [Stream.Write Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write?view=netcore-3.1), you can see the first parameter is Byte[], then pdfBase64 is string, I gues that you want to pass `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents)`