# Cast string to hex byte array

Tags: c#

I need to cast a string to a byte array in hex representation.
For example:

Value: 06000002
What I need is:

```
30 36 30 30 30 30 30 32
```

I tried to implicit convert all chars to byte as following:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[daten.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < daten.Length; i++)
{
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(daten[i]);
    
    bytes[i] = (byte)daten[i];
}
```

However I always get this result:

```
48 54 48 48 48 48 48 50
```

I do not need the result as string! I need it as byte array!

How do achive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: 48 decimal == 0x30 hexadecimal. 54 == 0x36 and 50 == 0x32.  You might also want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: @Flydog57, isn't that the perfect dupe?

Comment: I marked it as a dupe.  However, the conversion from a string to a byte array makes it not quite dup-y.  Note that PeterB has an answer below that assumes a character fits in a byte (that will never fail).  Jamiec is assuming UTF-8 encoding.  @Marvin, how are you planning to convert that string into a byte array (I notice that you have a variable named `daten`, which I'm guessing is German. A ß fits in a byte (it's a U+00DF), but just.  Lots of characters will not

Comment: @Flydog57 I need to cast a string (only numbers, length 8) into a byte array where the byte represents the value of the char as ascii hex value. Daten is the variable for which contains the string

Comment: Then your code works.  Just look at the values of the array in hex, not decimal.

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about a "hex byte array" but not a string. Byte arrays contain bytes, which are numbers. Numbers can be represented in an infinite number of bases. The way you see those representations is via a string. You see a string in the debug visualizer. You see a string when you output the variable via `Console.Write()`.

Comment: @Flydog57 how do I switch the mode from decimal to hex in Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: You can see a single value in hexadecimal in the debugger by appending `, h` to the end of the expression to evaluate.  For example, if you have a byte array `myArray`, and you want to see the value of first byte in hex, look at `myArray[0], h`.  You could also write a Data Visualizer for VS and plug it in (I did it once, I remember it as being pretty easy): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 6):

All you should need is:

```
var value = "06000002";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
```

In .NET 5 you can then use

```
string hexString = Convert.ToHexString(bytes);
```

To verify your result is what you expected

> 3036303030303032

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6sUmgE

Comment: As mentioned in my question above, I do not need it as string. I need the byte value itself representing the hex value. When I call the GetBytes method I get the bytes as dec value instead of hex

Comment: @MarvinKlein I'm sorry but that does not make sense. Bytes are bytes. There's no such thing as a "Hex byte" or a "dec byte". When you represent that data you can do so as base 10 (dec) or base 16 (hex) or whatever other numbering system you like.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you can convert each character to its hex representation:

```
var s = "06000002";
var bytes = s.Select(c => (byte) c);
var hexCodes = bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"));
```

You could stop here, or perhaps convert it to an Array or List.

Note that **bytes** are just **numbers**, there is no such thing as "hex bytes". The only time where "hex" exists is after conversion to string format, as I did above.

To still get it as one string you can proceed with this:

```
var result = string.Join(' ', hexCodes);
```

Or all in one go:

```
var result = string.Join(' ', "06000002".Select(c => ((byte) c).ToString("X2")));
```