# Why when converting string to byte[] using Convert.FromBase64String(...) i can't put two same characters?

Tags: c#

Why when converting string to byte[] using Convert.FromBase64String(...) i can't put two same characters?

For example I have

```
 class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var login = Console.ReadLine();
        var password = Console.ReadLine();
        var bytePass = Convert.FromBase64String(password);

        var user = new User() { Login = login, Password = bytePass };

    }
}
```

When I put as password string with two same characters ("testt" for example) it throw exception

> System.FormatException: „The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.”

What I should to do if I want convert string which multiple same characters to byte[]? Is it even possible?

Comment: You are using `FromBase64String` so the password is expected to be a `base64strin` and not `testt`

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String(...) converts a base64 encoded string to byte array. Your input string is not base64 encoded that's why you are getting this error. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Why are you using Convert.FromBase64String(...)?

Comment: @Alen.Toma so, is there a method that would do that?

Comment: @Chetan trying to convert string value to byte[] value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please tell me you're not going to store passwords without hashing and salting?

Comment: @DavidG take it easy, only trying to learn new things

Comment: @Chetan great, thats it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The string `testt` is not [a Base64-encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The length of a Base64 string must be a multiple of four.

To convert a regular string to a sequence of bytes, use [the `Encoding.GetBytes` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes).