# How can I create a byte (array) from a string?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

how can I create a byte data type from a string? For example: The device I am sending data to, expects the data to be in the hexadecimal format. More specifically, it needs to be in the format: `0x{hexa_decimal_value}`

Hard coded, it already worked sending data this way.
I would create a byte array like this:

```
byte[] items_to_send_ = new byte[] {0x46, 0x30, 0x00};
```

Now I want to code it dynamically.

The code I am now trying to write looks like this:

```
var ListByte = new List<byte>();

foreach (char val in messageToConvert)
{

    var hexa_decimal_val = Convert.ToInt32(val).ToString("X");
    hexa_decimal_val = $"0x:{hexa_decimal_val}";

    byte val_ = CreateByteFromStringFunction(hexa_decimal_val); // How? 


    ListByte.Add(val_); 

}
```

The step in question is when creating the variable `val_`, where I want to build the byte value from `hexa_decimal_val`, but I just don't know how. Casting does not work, and I did not find any other function that would do it for me.

It feels like there should be a really easy solution to this, but I just don't seem to find it.
What makes looking for the correct answer tricky here is that I already know how to convert from string to hexadecimal value, but the conversion afterwards is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Have you tried GetBytes() , see this doc [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-6.0)

Comment: byte[] ListByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageToConvert);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` converts a number in a string to an int. E.g., string `"123"` becomes int `123`.

Comment: The real question is why are you converting an `char` to an `Int32`, to a `String` and then to a `byte`? Why not just convert the `char` to a `byte`?

Comment: Bytes have no format. They're binary values. `hexadecimal format` that's a *string* format that requires multiple characters to represent the original byte.  If you convert that string back into a `byte` you'll get the original value back. What does that device *really* need? Bytes? Or sending 4 bytes representing that integer when just 1 would do? What does `messageToConvert` contain?

Comment: You can convert strings to bytes using `Encoding.GetBytes` provided you know what encoding is used by the device. For the 7-bit US-ASCII range every encoding would do. Even English text contains characters beyond that range though. If the device works with UTF8 you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. If it uses Latin1, `Encoding.Latin1.GetBytes()`. For other codepages you can use [Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Try following : string output = string.Join(" ", items_to_send_.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("x2")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do create bytes from characters one by one and append to a list. You can usethis;

```cs
var encodedByteList = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToConvert);
```

If you still want to do that, you can do something like this;

```cs
var encodedByteList = new List<byte>();

foreach (var character in messageToConvert)
{
    var correspondingByte = (byte)character;

    encodedByteList.Add(correspondingByte);
}
```

Or with LINQ, you can use this one liner;

```cs
var encodedByteList = messageToConvert.Select(c => (byte)c);
```

Comment: Thanks, totally overlooked that the 0xXX format was simply another representation. What I did not mention is that I need to add a termination character at the end. I simply do this now by converting to a List and then back to an array