# Convert a hex string to a byte in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a String like this:

```cs
String data = "0x0f";
```

and I would like to leave it as a single byte which represents this hex. Does anyone know what function I can use?

I tried using the following function:

```cs
public byte pegarValorHexText(string text)
{
    int NumberChars = text.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(text.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes[0];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Hogan I think the goal is to preserve the bytes which are written as hex to string.

Comment: @GuruStron no idea what you mean -- the answer I linked converts a string to bytes

Comment: That's right @Guru Stron

Comment: @Hogan the string clearly has bytes written as hex values. Those needed to be translated back to bytes.

Comment: @OtávioZordanAlves can you please explain a little bit more. What if there are more then 1 byte stored in the string, the goal is to get only the first one or what? Does it have maximum length?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? [`Convert.FromHexString(data.Replace("0x", ""))[0]` is available since .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring?view=net-5.0#system-convert-fromhexstring(system-string))

Comment: @Guru Stron The string has a hexadecimal value, it has a maximum of 4 characters, the sequence "0x" indicating that it is a hexadecimal value and a sequence of two hex chars

Comment: `byte.Parse("0x0f".Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The string has a hexadecimal value, it has a maximum of 4 characters, the sequence "0x" indicating that it is a hexadecimal value and a sequence of two hex chars

Just use `Convert.ToByte` then, it should handle the hex prefix:

```cs
byte b = Convert.ToByte("0x0f", 16); // 15
```